# Merging multiple combination matrices together

Tags: r

I have two matrices built from combinations

```
mat1 <- combn(10, 2)
mat2 <- combn(20, 3)
```

mat1 being a 2x45 and mat2 being a 3x1140.

What I want to produce is the possible combinations assuming you take both actions in sequence. So first 10 choose 2, followed immediately by 20 choose 3, what are all the combinations. I would like to produce a matrix which has 5 rows and 51300 columns. The first column values would be (1, 2, 1, 2, 3)

What is the most appropriate way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. Here is a solution that makes use of a couple Kronecker products:

```
one1 <- matrix(1, ncol = ncol(mat1))
one2 <- matrix(1, ncol = ncol(mat2))

rbind(mat1 %x% one2, one1 %x% mat2)
```

or

```
rbind(one2 %x% mat1, mat2 %x% one1)
```

depending on which combination matrix you want to recycle first.

Comment: (+1) for using `%x%`. Can you briefly explain how it works? The documentation is very limited.

Comment: maybe this link will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product. By making one of the two matrices a row of ones, I am effectively repeating the whole matrix, a little like what the `rep` function does for vectors. Using the same `rep` analogy again, the order of the arguments is the difference between using `times` or `each`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution using `expand.grid`:

```
idx = expand.grid((1:ncol(mat1)),(1:ncol(mat2)))

rbind(mat1[,idx[,1]], mat2[,idx[,2]])
```

---

Generalization to any number of matrices:

```
mat.list <- list(mat1, mat2)
idx <- expand.grid(lapply(lapply(mat.list, ncol), seq_len))
do.call(rbind, mapply(function(x, j)x[, j], mat.list, idx))
```